# What is the best way to fit data with multiple y-values per x-value and and get standard error at an extrapolated value?

Tags: regression, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am running an experiment where I am collecting data for 3 x-values, say `X = [x1, x2, x3]` (each `x > 0`).

For each of the x value, I am collecting 100 y values (it can be as high as 500 y values per x), i.e., `Y = [[y1_1, y1_2, ..., y1_100], [y2_1, y2_2, ..., y2_100], [y3_1, y3_2, ..., y3_100]]`.

I like to fit the data using both linear and quadratic regression and predict the y value at `x = 0`.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to fit the data? I thought of 2 approaches detailed below. Please suggest me the best way (from below or something new).

   - Get the mean and standard deviation of y values at each x, i.e., `new_Y = [y1_mean, y2_mean, y3_mean]` and `dY = [y1_stdev, y2_stdev, y3_stdev]`. Then, use, say, `numpy.polyfit` to perform a weighted regression with weight (w) being the inverse of standard deviations. (Or `scipy.curve_fit` with `x_data=X`, `ydata=Y`, and `sigma=dY`).
   - Extend the x values by repeating each value the number of observations (say, 100) times i.e., `new_X = [<x1 repeated a total of 100 times>, <x2 repeated a total of 100 times>, <x3 repeated a total of 100 times>]`. Then use the extended x values and y values in `numpy.polyfit` or `scipy.curve_fit` to do the regression.
2. My experimental y values have uncertainties. How to predict the uncertainty (maybe, standard deviation) of the extrapolated value, `y(x=0)`, from the experimental uncertainty of values for my choice of fitting function (linear/quadratic/or generic)?

Comment: This is genuinely unanswerable because any interpolation you do will depend far more on the assumed shape of the response curve than on the data -- and you have few distinguishable choices about the shape, given you have made observations at only three x values.  Absent a strong theory to support any such assumption, about the best you can do is fit a linear trend and test it for nonlinearity.  Anything else would be overfitting.

Comment: @whuber I am not asking about the best fitting function between linear and quadratic. Consider I will do a linear fit. Now, I am asking what is the best way to do regression on multiple Y values per X value and get uncertainty of an extrapolated value.

Comment: Understood.  My points remain: you could collect billions of data at each of your three x values and still will learn nothing more about how to interpolate between and beyond those values.

Comment: @whuber Given the data set as in my question and knowing that the data is likely to follow a linear trend, how would you extrapolate them and estimate uncertainty at the extrapolated value?

Comment: The same way you would with any such regression model: estimate the linear fit and apply its formula.  Standard formulas for confidence and prediction intervals apply.  Where complications can occur is when you have enough replicates at each $x_i$ to discern important differences among the distributions of the residuals (such as heteroscedasticity or non-Normality). How to proceed depends on the context; any underlying theory; the amount of data; your objectives; your opportunities for collecting more data; how far out you need to interpolate; *etc.*